# Query doesn't work on PHP but works directly in Mysql

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

When I log into mysql through terminal and run this:

```
update CAMPOSOCULTOSFORM set CAO_TITULO="Código" where CAO_TITULO="CÃ³digo";
```

Everything work's fine.

However, if I run this on PHP, there's no error but won't work:

```
$altera = 'update CAMPOSOCULTOSFORM set CAO_TITULO="Código" where CAO_TITULO="CÃ³digo"';
mysqli_query($conexao,$altera) or trigger_error("Query Failed! - Error: ".mysqli_error($conexao), E_USER_ERROR);
```

Where's the error?

Comment: There is problem with encoding, your PHP app using probably other than your database. It's problem not just in this query but in saving wrong character too...

Comment: Try reversing your quotes? IE `$altera = "update CAMPOSOCULTOSFORM set CAO_TITULO='Código' where CAO_TITULO='CÃ³digo'";`  Also try it without the special characters -- `$altera = "update CAMPOSOCULTOSFORM set CAO_TITULO='something' where CAO_TITULO='something_else'";`

Comment: You should check out the error log. I think you have problem with single and double quotes.

Comment: Where is this defined `$conexao`  How are you connecting to the DB, if you have no DB connection?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix the $conexao is working, there's other queries running fine before and after this one.

Comment: Have you tried it in a prepared statement?  Sometimes that can help with encoding issues.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix no I didin't, but just find out that all my columns have encoding equal to latin1_swedish_ci instead of UTF-8 and my page runs as UTF-8. What's the best solution to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Test pieces of code.

```
$altera = 'update CAMPOSOCULTOSFORM set CAO_TITULO="Codigo" where CAO_TITULO="CXdigo"';
```

Try encoding mysql connecting

```
$opcoes = array(
PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => 'SET NAMES UTF8');

         $this->conexao = new PDO("mysql:host=".DB_HOSTI.";charset=utf8;port=3306;dbname=".DB_DATABASEI, DB_USERNAMEI, DB_PASSWORDI, $opcoes);
         $this->conexao->exec("SET CHARACTER SET utf8");
         $this->conexao->exec("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
         $this->conexao->exec('SET character_set_connection=utf8');
         $this->conexao->exec('SET character_set_client=utf8');
         $this->conexao->exec('SET character_set_results=utf8');
```

**Edit**
Try a second idea!

```
 $altera = 'update CAMPOSOCULTOSFORM set replace(CAO_TITULO, "Ã³", "ó")';
```

Comment: Oi Adriano, obrigado pela sua resposta. Está salvo incorreto no banco de dados, então gerei um atualizador no PHP para fazer esta e outras correções. Antes não era UTF-8 o charset, foi na passada para UTF-8 que aconteceu isto :S

Comment: Sei que não é esta solução que procura, mas as vezes é melhor tentar por partes. Não vi erros no seu código...
na pior das hipoteses separe assim:
$altera = 'update CAMPOSOCULTOSFORM set CAO_TITULO="Código" where CAO_TITULO="C'.'Ã'.'³'.digo"';

Ou faça um store procedure direto no banco de dados para trocar tudo por lá.... assim faz tudo de uma vez!

Comment: As colunas estão com latin1_swedish_ci e não UTF-8. E agora, se eu mudar par UTF-8 será que vai quebrar a acentuação de todos os camposw

Comment: eu tentaria por partes até a string funcionar. Tente fazer uma function no mysql e passar os parametros:

update tabela set x = replace(x, 'Ã³', 'ó');

Comment: se você responder em inglês eu posso aceitar a sua resposta, acho que o Stack não vai aceitar a conversa em português sendo um fórum gringo, você estava certo é a codificação da tabela que está incorreta, aí não fecha com o script.

Comment: I'll write in english. Happy for help you!